# Plotting counts of a dataframe grouped by timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

So I have a pandas dataframe which has a large number of columns, and one of the columns is a timestamp in datetime format.  Each row in the dataframe represents a single "event".  What I'm trying to do is graph the frequency of these events over time.  Basically a simple bar graph showing how many events per month.

Started with this code:

```
data.groupby([(data.Timestamp.dt.year),(data.Timestamp.dt.month)]).count().plot(kind = 'bar')
plt.show()
```

This "kind of" works.  But there are 2 problems:

1) The graph comes with a legend which includes all the columns in the original data (like 30+ columns).  And each bar on the graph has a tiny sub-bar for each of the columns (all of which are the same value since I'm just counting events).

2) There are some months where there are zero events.  And these months don't show up on the graph at all.

I finally came up with code to get the graph looking the way I wanted.  But it seems to me that I'm not doing this the "correct" way, since this must be a fairly common usecase.

Basically I created a new dataframe with one column "count" and an index that's a string representation of month/year.  I populated that with zeroes over the time range I care about and then I copied over the data from the first frame into the new one.  Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cnt = data.groupby([(data.Timestamp.dt.year),(data.Timestamp.dt.month)]).count()
index = []
for year in [2015, 2016, 2017, 2018]:
    for month in range(1,13):
        index.append('%04d-%02d'%(year, month))

cnt_new = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=['count'])
cnt_new = cnt_new.fillna(0)
for i, row in cnt.iterrows():
    cnt_new.at['%04d-%02d'%i,'count'] = row[0]
cnt_new.plot(kind = 'bar')

plt.show()
```

Anyone know an easier way to go about this?

EDIT -->  Per request, here's an idea of the type of dataframe.  It's the results from an SQL query.  Actual data is my company's so...

```
              Timestamp     FirstName    LastName  HairColor \
0   2018-11-30 02:16:11     Fred         Schwartz  brown
1   2018-11-29 16:25:55     Sam          Smith     black
2   2018-11-19 21:12:29     Helen        Hunt      red
```

OK, so I think I got it.  Thanks to Yuca for resample command.  I just need to run that on the Timestamp data series (rather than on the whole dataframe) and it gives me exactly what I was looking for.

```
> data.index = data.Timestamp
> data.Timestamp.resample('M').count()
Timestamp
2017-11-30    0
2017-12-31    0
2018-01-31    1
2018-02-28    2
2018-03-31    7
2018-04-30    9
2018-05-31    2
2018-06-30    6
2018-07-31    5
2018-08-31    4
2018-09-30    1
2018-10-31    0
2018-11-30    5
```

Comment: Please share a sample of your dataframe

Comment: with a sample that small is hard to provide a comprehensive solution, so be patient

Comment: FYI, we're talking about 200 rows and 30-40 columns.  Nothing huge.  I could alter my SQL query to get a single timestamp column if that helps.  But I'm making other graphs with the same data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So OP request is: "Basically a simple bar graph showing how many events per month"

Using `pd.resample` and monthly frequency yields the desired result

```
df[['FirstName']].resample('M').count()
```

Output:

```
             FirstName  
Timestamp                                 
2018-11-30          3
```

To include non observed months, we need to create a baseline calendar

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame(index = pd.date_range(df.index[0].date(), periods=12, freq='M'))
```

and then assign to it the result of our resample

```
df_a['count'] = df[['FirstName']].resample('M').count()
```

Output:

```
            count
2018-11-30    3.0
2018-12-31    NaN
2019-01-31    NaN
2019-02-28    NaN
2019-03-31    NaN
2019-04-30    NaN
2019-05-31    NaN
2019-06-30    NaN
2019-07-31    NaN
2019-08-31    NaN
2019-09-30    NaN
2019-10-31    NaN
```

Comment: This is part of it, thanks for the "resample" command.  I will read up on that.  But what I was hoping for is a dataframe with a single column titled "count" rather than 3 columns (or in my actual case 30+ columns).

Comment: And I was hoping I could have a row for each month in the past 4 years, even if none of the original data have timestamps in that month.

Comment: I updated to have only one column. As for the missing months, you need to create a range index a do some stuff. Let me find the code for that and update my answer